# How to import any library into angular project with systemjs and @types

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, systemjs, typescript-typings

Hei,

So I'm playing a bit with SystemJS as I had problems with webpack when trying to do same things (import 3rd party libraries or npm modules into project). So for this example let's take MQTT library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) and basic Angular 2 project (quickstart). So nothing complicated, only couple of files to test configuration. My systemjs.config.js looks like this:

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: { 'npm:': 'node_modules/' },
    map: { app: 'app',
     '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
     'mqtt': 'npm:mqtt/mqtt.js'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

And in app.component.ts:

```
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt';
```

However in console logs (when starting the app) I don't even see that /node_modules/mqtt was required and therefore I also get that mqtt is undefined when trying to debug it in chrome.

I start app with normal lite-server.

I know that this may be a wrong way so let me explain what else did I try. In first try I had also @types/mqtt (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mqtt) installed and then required it the same way.

What is the right way to do it. Especially if a 3rd party library is made for "backend use" and it doesn't have d.ts file inside? I know that @types come to help in this case but how? How do you connect those in frontend through systemjs and do they work also in production with let's say express server?

Comment: Can you check what JavaScript is generated by `tsc` and how does it require `mqtt`? SystemJS has nothing to do with `@types` so if it compiled correctly than you might not be importing it properly.

Comment: I don't even see it in compiled .js version...